# What is matrix_basis?

Tags: python, scripting, objects

I'm trying to use Blender as my GUI content creator, and I'm writing plugins for it.

I have a brief look on the API document and noticed that *Object*s have three matrices: world, local and basis. It is pretty easy to understand world and local matrix, and they work as I expected. However, I don't get the concept of basis matrix, and it can be disturbed by *Alt-O* hotkey.

Although it seems local and world matrix is enough for me, I am still curious about the meaning of the basis matrix. So what does basis matrix stands for?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/relationship-between-global-vertex-coordinates-and-mesh-objects-matrix-attribut/32608?s=4|0.1769#32608  isn't an answer, but it might have elements that lead you closer to understanding.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the documentation it states:

> Matrix access to location, rotation and scale (including deltas),
>   before constraints and parenting are applied

The key is that it is the matrix before constraints are applied, as some constraints can alter the local matrix.

[API docs - bpy.types.Object](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_release/bpy.types.Object.html?highlight=object)

Comment: It's also worth mentioning it's role in other matrices: `matrix_local = matrix_parent_inverse * matrix_basis`, and `matrix_world = parent.matrix_world * matrix_local`.

Comment: ^ This part should really be in the documentation

Comment: Just a note for posterity: in blender 2.8 you use the `@` operator to multiply matrices, so `matrix_local = matrix_parent_inverse @ matrix_basis` and `matrix_world = parent.matrix_world @ matrix_local`