# How to calculate the angles between axis and bounding box normals?

Tags: python, coordinates

I would like to determine the torsion of an object bounding box in reference to the global coordinate system (such that for a axis aligned object all angles will be 0).

My idea was to create a bounding box object `bb` via `bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add()` and copy its parameters from the object `obj`:

```
centre = sum((Vector(b) for b in obj.bound_box), Vector())
bb.dimensions = obj.dimensions
bb.rotation_euler = obj.rotation_euler
bb.location = (centre[0], centre[1], centre[2])
bb.location = obj.matrix_world * bb.location
```

Than I tried to calculate the angles:

```
for poly in obj.data.polygons:
    # angle of bb normal against z axis
    angle = Vector((0,0,1)).angle(obj.matrix_world * poly.normal)
    print("%6i  %.3f°" % (poly.index, degrees(angle)))
```

But the values don't make any sense. I am not sure whether this is a good approach at all.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: Another idea might be to align the object to the axis somehow an than read out the difference from ``rotation_euler``

Comment: What you're looking for is the `Vector.rotation_difference` function. It gives you the angle between two vectors. https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/mathutils.html?highlight=rotation_difference#mathutils.Vector.rotation_difference

Comment: It is unclear what you mean by "torsion".  The obj.rotation_euler describes how the object is transformed from the world coordinate system.  Each of the normals of the bounding box point in a different direction, so the angle between that normal and the z axis will vary.  You probably need to sit down and think about your question.  How does your question apply to a sphere? how would it apply to Suzanne (the monkey head)?  How would it apply to to a boomerang model?

Comment: @MutantBob Sorry for my unclear explanation. I try to rephrase: Considering Suzanne (or any complex objects) I would take its bounding box cuboid. So let's imagine a cuboid with a arbitrary position and rotation in the scene. Now I like to know which rotation I have to apply on the cuboid on each axis to reach axis alignment. But I am thinking now about your hint, maybe the solution is simply the euler rotation?

Comment: @TLousky Thanks for your hint, the functions gives the same result though. But it confirms that the problem is not the angular calculation but the bounding box normal vectors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The orientation of an object is `obj.rotation_euler` or `obj.rotation_quaternion` (and whichever one does not match the object's `rotation_mode` can be invalid or inaccurate).

The orientation can also be recovered from `obj.matrix_world.decompose()[1]`, but that's a little bit of overkill.

For a slightly deeper dive down the rabbit hole, check out [Relationship between global vertex coordinates and mesh object's matrix attributes](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15240/relationship-between-global-vertex-coordinates-and-mesh-objects-matrix-attribut) .